# R: How does stat_density_ridges modify and plot data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

<Disclaimer(s) - (1) This is my first post, so please be gentle, specifically regarding formatting and (2) I did try to dig as much as I could on this topic before posting the question here>

I have a simple data vector containing returns of 40 portfolios on the same day:

```
Year    Return
Now -17.39862061
Now -12.98954582
Now -12.98954582
Now -12.86928749
Now -12.37044334
Now -11.07007504
Now -10.68971539
Now -10.07578182
Now -9.984867096
Now -8.764036179
Now -8.698093414
Now -8.594026566
Now -8.193638802
Now -7.818599701
Now -7.622627735
Now -7.535216808
Now -7.391239166
Now -7.331315517
Now -5.58059597
Now -5.579797268
Now -4.525201797
Now -3.735909224
Now -2.687532902
Now -2.65363884
Now -2.177522898
Now -1.977644682
Now -1.353205681
Now -0.042584345
Now 0.096564181
Now 0.275416046
Now 0.638839543
Now 1.959529042
Now 3.715519428
Now 4.842819691
Now 5.475946426
Now 6.380955219
Now 6.535937309
Now 8.421762466
Now 8.556800842
Now 10.39185524
```

I am trying to plot these returns to compare versus other days (so the rest of my history e.g.). I tried to use stat_density_ridges as per the code block below

```
      ggplot(data = data.plot, aes(x = Return, y = Year, fill = factor(..quantile..))) +
      
      stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient",calc_ecdf = TRUE,
                          quantiles = c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975),
                          quantile_lines = TRUE)
```

As you can see - the "year" in this case is the same i.e. there is no height parameter, yet I get a nice ridg(y) chart. While the chart is beautiful to behold, and very very awesome, I am at a loss to determine how the plotting function is computing the density in this case, specially the height.

This is the output chart I get (I have omitted the formatting code here since it doesn't make a difference to my question):

[Portfolio Return Distribution Plots - US versus Europe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcvKk.png)

I tried digging into the code of the function itself, but came up with a total blank. The documentation didn't help (except perhaps give me a hint that the function plots continous distributions).

Any help, or guidance, or even a nudge in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: This tutorial explains it well: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/443163_b891d4460db542898b5d86b1e9c3e1b6.html

Comment: Thanks jared_mamrot! This does the trick.

Comment: Just to add, to those facing issues like me. There is also a dependence between the various distributions in case you are using this function - the plots I get if using the data illustrated above in of itself, versus using it with other years data differs. The kernel density estimates (and the resultant distribution plots) are skewed towards a joint bandwidth estimate (parameter bw in the tutorial linked above). If I have multiple data series, and I am trying to plot them together as ridges, then the bandwidth estimation is done jointly - which changes the plot.

Comment: I am certain there are ways of estimating the optimal bandwidth individually based on the data samples - but that is something to be aware of if/while using this functionality.